# How to remove track from MediaStream and "stop" webcam?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, getusermedia

I'm trying to remove a track from a MediaStream. `MediaStream.removeTrack()` removes the track from the stream, but the camera light is left on indicating that the camera is still active.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMediaStreamTrack

This references a `stop()` method which I suppose would stop the camera completely, In chrome however I get `"Object MediaStreamTrack has no method 'stop'"`

Is there a way around this or do I have to stop the whole stream and then recreate it with the tracks I don't want gone? As an example, I want to remove the video track while the audiotrack is still there.

Answer (score 14):

`MediaStreamTrack.stop()` is now [added](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/stop) to the Chrome.

`MediaStream.stop()` is [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/mediastream-deprecations?hl=en) in Chrome 45.

You should use `MediaStream.getVideoTracks()` to get video tracks and stop the track using `MediaStreamTrack.stop()`

Comment: I wonder how this design decision was motivated. Is there a discussion somewhere?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/mediastream-deprecations/#stop-ended-and-active

Answer (score 1):

for stopping specific media stream, Maybe this help: ([Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/stop))

```
function stopStreamedVideo(videoElem) {
  const stream = videoElem.srcObject;
  const tracks = stream.getTracks();

  tracks.forEach(function(track) {
    track.stop();
  });

  videoElem.srcObject = null;
}
```

Comment: good one, though you might also want to call `stream.removeTrack(track)` after stopping the track, if you wish to later use the stream again

Answer (score 0):

You need to call stop() on the MediaStream, not a MediaStreamTrack.

Take a look at [simpl.info/gum](http://simpl.info/gum). From the console, call `stream.stop()`: recording stops and the video camera light goes off.

Comment: No, not if I only want to stop one track. Each MediaStream have two tracks, audio and video. If I call stop on the MediaStream it will end everything.

Comment: Ah -- so you want stop the video, but keep the audio? Not sure if this does what you want, but how about `track.enabled = false`? Light stays on though, i.e. camera is still 'running'.

Comment: The MediaStreamTrack `stop()` method hasn't been implemented in Chrome or Firefox, though it's in the spec:  http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html#dom-mediastreamtrack-stop

Comment: Exactly. That's a bummer, personally I rely quite much on my webcam light when I'm in applications. If its on I'm not convinced that It isn't used. I guess I have to stop the whole stream and then do a new getUserMedia call for now.

Comment: Thanks for the enabled property tip, much better than removing/adding as I did before.

Comment: Yeah, but as Sam Dutton mentioned, `track.enabled` doesn't make the camera light go off.

Comment: Have you found a way to make the camera light go off? I can't stop the tracks. I can't disable/remove them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the proper way to deal with this issue is to stop your `MediaStream`, recreate (and reattach) it as an audio-only one and then renegotiate the `PeerConnection` session. Unfortunately, Firefox currently [doesn't support](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=857115) renegotiation mid-session.

The only viable hack is thus to also recreate the `PeerConnection` with the new `MediaStream` as suggested [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/09/webrtc-update-and-workarounds/) (see "Adding video mid-call").